# creating media controls on android wear

Tags: wear-os

I want to create a wear application that has 2 mode : the connected mode and the disconnected mode. The first mode is used when the watch is connected to the bluetooth : you can control a media player and have the basic controls on what's being played on the phone.

The second mode is used when the mobile is not paired to the watch : you can listen to content on the watch with a bluetooth headset.

My question is the following : on the connected mode, I created my own interface with the basic controls (play/pause/next/previous) and I can synchronize the controls with the phone sending messages via the message api.

Is there a better way to do? Like using the Notifications?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the basic media controls on your wear device (controlling then playback of your media app on your phone), then you can use the MediaSessionCompat to handle that for you; take a look at the [UniversalMusicPlayer](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer) for example; basically if your media app is using the MediaSessionCompat (or MediaSession if you are not concerned with earlier versions of Android), then the basic controls should appear on your watch and if you implement MediSessionComapt.Callback in your media app, framework will send the control commands to your app from your watch.

Comment: what if we don't want to create MediaSession? then is there any way to do this?